# How to execute cucumber scenario using command line?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I am using selenium webdriver and Junit. I am able to run the tests from jenkin. What are the commands to run that tests or scenario from command line?

Comment: Use the cucumber.api.cli.Main class and provide the options necessary. You can get the options by using '--help' as argument to this class. Or check out the contents of this question to get them ready made - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696842/usage-java-cucumber-api-cli-main-options-filedirlineline/43706445

Comment: If you have some sort of testrunner class such as : http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/junit-test-runner-class/ then you can just run by "mvn test" make sure yo name this class either Test* or *Test so that it is recognised as the runner class.